# eth-brownie: ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'

Tags: solidity, python

I was doing the Patrick Collins 16 hours tutorial [link](https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=17887) and I got this error. I have been looking on lot of threads about this but could not solve it.

My code:

deploy.py

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network

def deploy_simple_storage():
account = get_account()
simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
print(stored_value)
transaction = simple_storage.store(15, {"from": account})
transaction.wait(1)
updated_stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
print(updated_stored_value)


def get_account():
if network.show_active() == "development":
    return accounts[0]
else:
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
deploy_simple_storage()
```

.env

```
  export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
  export PRIVATE_KEY='0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

brownie-config.yaml

```
dotenv: .env
wallets:
from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

---

I was running "brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby" when I got this error.

Comment: Is your `.env` file in your brownie project directory (the one containing `brownie-config.yaml`)?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your `brownie-config.yaml` properly with proper indentations as they are indentation sensitive.
As follow:

```
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```